# Python/Pyside chrashes without error message

Tags: python, macos, osx-lion, pyside

i've just installed python (Python 2.7.6) with pyside (Version 1.2.1) on Mac OS Lion 10.7.5
 via Macports.

When I wanted to test this very simple code, python crashes unexpectedly:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
app.exec_()
```

whereas

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from PyQt4 import Qt

app = Qt.QApplication(sys.argv)
app.exec_()
```

works fine. (Even if it doesn't show anything, it's just a bare application)

The Problem is, that python just chrashes and doesn't show up any error message. Does anyone has an idea what to do now?

Here is the report generated by Mac OS:

```
Process:         Python [1494]
Path:            /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:      Python
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  Python [1450]

Date/Time:       2014-01-10 16:44:52.411 +0100
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.5 (11G63)
Report Version:  9

Interval Since Last Report:          9814 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           29
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   28
Anonymous UUID:                      FA6527AF-EC91-4B5B-B1B3-23AF3ED13089

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000

VM Regions Near 0:
--> 
    __TEXT                 000000010f1ce000-000000010f1d0000 [    8K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python

Application Specific Information:
objc[1494]: garbage collection is OFF

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c5b64f0 strlen + 16
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c55234b strdup + 18
2   libshiboken-python2.7.1.2.dylib 0x00000001133960dd Shiboken::sequenceToArgcArgv(_object*, int*, char***, char const*) + 427
3   QtGui.so                        0x0000000113d37bf7 QApplicationConstructorStart(_object*) + 69
4   QtGui.so                        0x0000000113d38e08 Sbk_QApplication_Init + 384
5   org.python.python               0x000000010f2306d4 type_call + 372
6   org.python.python               0x000000010f1df521 PyObject_Call + 97
7   org.python.python               0x000000010f270dda PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 10618
8   org.python.python               0x000000010f26e416 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1990
9   org.python.python               0x000000010f26dc46 PyEval_EvalCode + 54
10  org.python.python               0x000000010f294d9e PyRun_FileExFlags + 174
11  org.python.python               0x000000010f26a2ca builtin_execfile + 490
12  org.python.python               0x000000010f270b17 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 9911
13  org.python.python               0x000000010f26e416 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1990
14  org.python.python               0x000000010f275a0d fast_function + 285
15  org.python.python               0x000000010f270bb8 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 10072
16  org.python.python               0x000000010f26e416 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1990
17  org.python.python               0x000000010f2700e6 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 7302
18  org.python.python               0x000000010f26e416 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1990
19  org.python.python               0x000000010f275a0d fast_function + 285
20  org.python.python               0x000000010f270bb8 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 10072
21  org.python.python               0x000000010f26e416 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1990
22  org.python.python               0x000000010f275a0d fast_function + 285
23  org.python.python               0x000000010f270bb8 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 10072
24  org.python.python               0x000000010f26e416 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1990
25  org.python.python               0x000000010f275a0d fast_function + 285
26  org.python.python               0x000000010f270bb8 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 10072
27  org.python.python               0x000000010f26e416 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1990
28  org.python.python               0x000000010f275a0d fast_function + 285
29  org.python.python               0x000000010f270bb8 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 10072
30  org.python.python               0x000000010f26e416 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1990
31  org.python.python               0x000000010f275a0d fast_function + 285
32  org.python.python               0x000000010f270bb8 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 10072
33  org.python.python               0x000000010f26e416 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1990
34  org.python.python               0x000000010f20307b function_call + 347
35  org.python.python               0x000000010f1df521 PyObject_Call + 97
36  org.python.python               0x000000010f272f76 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 19222
37  org.python.python               0x000000010f26e416 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1990
38  org.python.python               0x000000010f20307b function_call + 347
39  org.python.python               0x000000010f1df521 PyObject_Call + 97
40  org.python.python               0x000000010f272f76 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 19222
41  org.python.python               0x000000010f26e416 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1990
42  org.python.python               0x000000010f275a0d fast_function + 285
43  org.python.python               0x000000010f270bb8 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 10072
44  org.python.python               0x000000010f26e416 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1990
45  org.python.python               0x000000010f275a0d fast_function + 285
46  org.python.python               0x000000010f270bb8 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 10072
47  org.python.python               0x000000010f26e416 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1990
48  org.python.python               0x000000010f20307b function_call + 347
49  org.python.python               0x000000010f1df521 PyObject_Call + 97
50  org.python.python               0x000000010f272f76 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 19222
51  org.python.python               0x000000010f26e416 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1990
52  org.python.python               0x000000010f275a0d fast_function + 285
53  org.python.python               0x000000010f270bb8 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 10072
54  org.python.python               0x000000010f26e416 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1990
55  org.python.python               0x000000010f275a0d fast_function + 285
56  org.python.python               0x000000010f270bb8 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 10072
57  org.python.python               0x000000010f26e416 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1990
58  org.python.python               0x000000010f275a0d fast_function + 285
59  org.python.python               0x000000010f270bb8 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 10072
60  org.python.python               0x000000010f26e416 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1990
61  org.python.python               0x000000010f275a0d fast_function + 285
62  org.python.python               0x000000010f270bb8 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 10072
63  org.python.python               0x000000010f26e416 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1990
64  org.python.python               0x000000010f26dc46 PyEval_EvalCode + 54
65  org.python.python               0x000000010f294d9e PyRun_FileExFlags + 174
66  org.python.python               0x000000010f294900 PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 768
67  org.python.python               0x000000010f2a87a8 Py_Main + 2952
68  org.python.python               0x000000010f1cff24 0x10f1ce000 + 7972

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8f637d7a __recvfrom + 10
1   _socket.so                      0x000000011063e39c sock_recv_guts + 460
2   _socket.so                      0x000000011063cfc1 sock_recv + 129
3   org.python.python               0x000000010f272f5f PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 19199
4   org.python.python               0x000000010f26e416 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1990
5   org.python.python               0x000000010f275a0d fast_function + 285
6   org.python.python               0x000000010f270bb8 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 10072
7   org.python.python               0x000000010f26e416 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1990
8   org.python.python               0x000000010f275a0d fast_function + 285
9   org.python.python               0x000000010f270bb8 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 10072
10  org.python.python               0x000000010f2759a2 fast_function + 178
11  org.python.python               0x000000010f270bb8 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 10072
12  org.python.python               0x000000010f2759a2 fast_function + 178
13  org.python.python               0x000000010f270bb8 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 10072
14  org.python.python               0x000000010f26e416 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1990
15  org.python.python               0x000000010f20307b function_call + 347
16  org.python.python               0x000000010f1df521 PyObject_Call + 97
17  org.python.python               0x000000010f1eb196 instancemethod_call + 502
18  org.python.python               0x000000010f1df521 PyObject_Call + 97
19  org.python.python               0x000000010f2751b8 PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 168
20  org.python.python               0x000000010f2aab46 t_bootstrap + 70
21  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c5628bf _pthread_start + 335
22  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c565b75 thread_start + 13

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8f6387e6 kevent + 10
1   libzmq.3.dylib                  0x0000000110f075c9 zmq::kqueue_t::loop() + 165
2   libzmq.3.dylib                  0x0000000110f198ce thread_routine + 106
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c5628bf _pthread_start + 335
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c565b75 thread_start + 13

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8f6387e6 kevent + 10
1   libzmq.3.dylib                  0x0000000110f075c9 zmq::kqueue_t::loop() + 165
2   libzmq.3.dylib                  0x0000000110f198ce thread_routine + 106
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c5628bf _pthread_start + 335
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c565b75 thread_start + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8f638a7a poll + 10
1   libzmq.3.dylib                  0x0000000110f1fa47 zmq_poll + 460
2   libzmq.3.dylib                  0x0000000110f0eb4c zmq::proxy(zmq::socket_base_t*, zmq::socket_base_t*, zmq::socket_base_t*) + 138
3   _device.so                      0x0000000110fb02be __pyx_pw_3zmq_7backend_6cython_7_device_3proxy + 926
4   org.python.python               0x000000010f1df521 PyObject_Call + 97
5   _device.so                      0x0000000110fb144a __pyx_pw_3zmq_7backend_6cython_7_device_1device + 1130
6   org.python.python               0x000000010f270b17 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 9911
7   org.python.python               0x000000010f2759a2 fast_function + 178
8   org.python.python               0x000000010f270bb8 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 10072
9   org.python.python               0x000000010f2759a2 fast_function + 178
10  org.python.python               0x000000010f270bb8 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 10072
11  org.python.python               0x000000010f26e416 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1990
12  org.python.python               0x000000010f20307b function_call + 347
13  org.python.python               0x000000010f1df521 PyObject_Call + 97
14  org.python.python               0x000000010f1eb196 instancemethod_call + 502
15  org.python.python               0x000000010f1df521 PyObject_Call + 97
16  org.python.python               0x000000010f2751b8 PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 168
17  org.python.python               0x000000010f2aab46 t_bootstrap + 70
18  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c5628bf _pthread_start + 335
19  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c565b75 thread_start + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8f6387e6 kevent + 10
1   libzmq.3.dylib                  0x0000000110f075c9 zmq::kqueue_t::loop() + 165
2   libzmq.3.dylib                  0x0000000110f198ce thread_routine + 106
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c5628bf _pthread_start + 335
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c565b75 thread_start + 13

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8f6387e6 kevent + 10
1   libzmq.3.dylib                  0x0000000110f075c9 zmq::kqueue_t::loop() + 165
2   libzmq.3.dylib                  0x0000000110f198ce thread_routine + 106
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c5628bf _pthread_start + 335
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c565b75 thread_start + 13

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8f637bca __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c566274 _pthread_cond_wait + 840
2   org.python.python               0x000000010f2a6541 PyThread_acquire_lock + 97
3   org.python.python               0x000000010f26d97d PyEval_RestoreThread + 61
4   _sqlite3.so                     0x0000000110cebd39 pysqlite_step + 41
5   _sqlite3.so                     0x0000000110ce6fa8 pysqlite_connection_commit + 232
6   org.python.python               0x000000010f1df521 PyObject_Call + 97
7   org.python.python               0x000000010f1df6ff call_function_tail + 95
8   org.python.python               0x000000010f1df96e PyObject_CallMethod + 318
9   _sqlite3.so                     0x0000000110ce862c pysqlite_connection_exit + 124
10  org.python.python               0x000000010f1df521 PyObject_Call + 97
11  org.python.python               0x000000010f1da37e PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs + 382
12  org.python.python               0x000000010f27269e PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 16958
13  org.python.python               0x000000010f26e416 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1990
14  org.python.python               0x000000010f275a0d fast_function + 285
15  org.python.python               0x000000010f270bb8 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 10072
16  org.python.python               0x000000010f26e416 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1990
17  org.python.python               0x000000010f20307b function_call + 347
18  org.python.python               0x000000010f1df521 PyObject_Call + 97
19  org.python.python               0x000000010f272f76 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 19222
20  org.python.python               0x000000010f26e416 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1990
21  org.python.python               0x000000010f275a0d fast_function + 285
22  org.python.python               0x000000010f270bb8 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 10072
23  org.python.python               0x000000010f26e416 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1990
24  org.python.python               0x000000010f275a0d fast_function + 285
25  org.python.python               0x000000010f270bb8 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 10072
26  org.python.python               0x000000010f26e416 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1990
27  org.python.python               0x000000010f20307b function_call + 347
28  org.python.python               0x000000010f1df521 PyObject_Call + 97
29  org.python.python               0x000000010f272f76 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 19222
30  org.python.python               0x000000010f26e416 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1990
31  org.python.python               0x000000010f275a0d fast_function + 285
32  org.python.python               0x000000010f270bb8 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 10072
33  org.python.python               0x000000010f2759a2 fast_function + 178
34  org.python.python               0x000000010f270bb8 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 10072
35  org.python.python               0x000000010f2759a2 fast_function + 178
36  org.python.python               0x000000010f270bb8 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 10072
37  org.python.python               0x000000010f26e416 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1990
38  org.python.python               0x000000010f20307b function_call + 347
39  org.python.python               0x000000010f1df521 PyObject_Call + 97
40  org.python.python               0x000000010f1eb196 instancemethod_call + 502
41  org.python.python               0x000000010f1df521 PyObject_Call + 97
42  org.python.python               0x000000010f2751b8 PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 168
43  org.python.python               0x000000010f2aab46 t_bootstrap + 70
44  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c5628bf _pthread_start + 335
45  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c565b75 thread_start + 13

Thread 8:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8f6387e6 kevent + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff9172e786 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 923
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff9172d316 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 54
```

Answer (score 2):

The example app at [QT Wiki](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Hello-World-in-PySide) is slightly different. Try that exact script on your system. Try running your script via

> python script.py

It looks like the crash is caused from parsing sys.argv. Check your system logs leading up to the crash. Try other QT applications on your system to see if there is an error there.